# Testing D3 inside a functional component with Jest and Enzyme

Tags: d3.js, functional-programming, jestjs, enzyme, cheerio

I'm trying to test the creation of a scatter chart created inside a functional component.  I've tried a bunch of packages:
Jest/Enzyme, Cheerio,  react-test-renderer,  testing-library, to name a few.

the html looks like this:

```
 <div className="outerDiv" data-test='scatterchart'>
    <div ref={wrapperRef} className="corrD3_wrapperDiv">
      <svg ref={svgRef} className="corrD3_svgBox" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <defs>
          <clipPath id={chartId}>
            <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" />
          </clipPath>
        </defs>
        <g className="x-axis" />
        <g className="y-axis" />
        <g className="content" clipPath={`url(#${chartId})`} />
      </svg>
    </div>
  </div >
```

D3 is generated inside a useEffect.

I mock up the useEffect in my test code:

```
const mockUseEffect = () => {
  useEffect.mockImplementation(f => f());
};

useEffect = jest.spyOn(React, 'useEffect');
mockUseEffect();
```

I run the tests inside a timeout to allow for the useEffects.
found on StackOverflow:

```
// This is helper that I'm using to wrap test function calls
const withTimeout = (done, fn) => {
 const timeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
    fn();
    clearTimeout(timeoutId);
    done();
  });
};


it('Should load component after timeout', done => withTimeout(done, () => {
  let component;
  component = mount(<Scatter2 {...props} />)
  const $ = cheerio.load(component.html());

  expect($('svg')).toHaveLength(1);
  expect($('circle')).toHaveLength(20);  <-- FAILS
}));
```

No matter what I do I can't get the D3 to generate before the test runs.

Does anybody have any suggestions as to what I can do?
I cannot figure this out.

Thanks,
Jed K

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried wrapping it in an async await instead?

```
import { wait } from "@testing-library/react";

it('Should load component after timeout', async () => {
    let component;
    component = mount(<Scatter2 {...props} />)
    const $ = cheerio.load(component.html());
    await wait(() => {
        expect($('svg')).toHaveLength(1);
        expect($('circle')).toHaveLength(20);
    });
```